# How to set a maximum time in jobInfo so that the job will be canceled after this time?

Tags: android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I have a jobService schedule a job

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new Builder(JOB_ID);
builder.setBackoffCriteria(/*initial 3 min*/ INI_TIME, /*increase exponential*/ JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL);
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED);
```

I want to set a maximum delay of 1 day, so that the job will be canceled after 1 day, it doesn't meet all the requirements. I was thinking about using `setOverrideDeadline(1d)` but it will execute the job by the 1 day deadline. and `setTriggerContentMaxDelay`works the same. Actually I'm wondering the difference between `setTriggerContentMaxDelay` and `setOverrideDeadline`

Answer (score 0):

Neither [setOverrideDeadline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setOverrideDeadline(long)) nor [setTriggerContentMaxDelay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setTriggerContentMaxDelay(long)) are the right methods to use in your scenario. setTriggerContentMaxDelay is only used when you set at least one content URI trigger using [addTriggerContentUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)).

If you want to cancel the job after 24 hours, I would simply use AlarmManager to set an alarm to cancel the job using the JOB_ID after 24 hours. You can check to see if the job is present using:

```
JobScheduler mScheduler = (JobScheduler)
        mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
for (JobInfo jobInfo : mScheduler.getAllPendingJobs()) {
    if (jobID == jobInfo.getId()) {
        // Cancel job
    }
}
```

Or you can cancel the alarm when your job executes.

Comment: The problem with using AlarmManager are the permission requirements. If this is a pivotal feature, that you don't want users to disable by denying the permissions, you put yourself in a pickle with your solution. he should be able to use setOverrideDeadline with combination of setBackoffCriteria to accomplish what he wants.